# Safari on iOS devices is loading corrupted images - Wordpress site

Tags: ios, wordpress, mobile-safari

The images in question are JPEGs and I've gotten them down to a smaller size (30kb). The wordpress site in question is responsive and this issue on happens when I'm using mobile network to load the site. Wirelessly, it has no issues but on 3G/4G, images loaded randomly, some are corrupted, images swap places, so all css and js seems messed up. I'm using W3 cache to enhance the speed, but nothing is helping. Some images are half grey, black and look corrupted sometimes. This only happens on iOS devices with safari browser.

Anyone else faced the same issue? On desktop being wired, wireless, I've never had this issue.

Not sure if it has to do with with database or overall site performance of the server. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue today. When clearing the mobile browser cache, the "problem images" changed and different images were swapped or corrupted. Like you, my issue goes away on wifi. Our static asses are served by Akamai, so server-side speed should not be an issue. We are not running Wordpress, so that is also not the core problem.

The issue was found on an iPhone 4S running iOS 8.1 and communicating over 4G. Same device on wifi did not have the corruption/swapping problem.

Comment: Apparently this is not a new or uncommon issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6563683

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I did some research and found out that there was some restriction for ajax content size getting loaded on safari with 3g/4g service. I haven't found a solution though. It's affecting all iOS devices and not just iPhone 4S.

Comment: Does this happen if you use the Chrome app as a browser instead of Safari?

Comment: Have you tried using a cloud image optimization solution like Cloudinary? It  would optimize the images based on what's best for the browser. If its an image size issue, this service would certainly help. We use it in production for our news sites, and it does amazing things for pageload performance because we have so many pictures.

Answer (score 1):

While supporting our WordPress Clients, I've faced such an issue dozens of times There are two general reasons for such a behavior:

1. You're using some CDN (Content Delivery Network) which you didn't mention in your question, and different CDN servers output different website cache version. If you're using CDN, try to purge your local plugin's cache, disable your local plugin and purge your CDN cache.
2. Sometimes images thumbnails may be corrupted, while they still exist. Try installing "[Force Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/)" plugin and regenerate all the thumbnails.

Though two above reasons are the most common, the issue itself may be connected with something else as well, for example, with some particular plugin. For this case it might be a good idea to temporarily deactivate your plugins one after another and see if the issue is resolved.

In case any of these won't help, it will require some debug work, so it could be a good idea to hire some WordPress developer for about an hour to fix this.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a mac + safari you can try remote debugging your iOS device. If you do this you could  open the developer toolbar for the device so you can see if the information is actually being loaded. ie. if the messed up image is 300k on the desktop site, but the iOS device is loading a 30k image, you would know you're losing data somewhere.

I've not seen this specific issue, but I've had similar issues pop up due to bad CDN links, caching plugins, and lazy loading of images.

Another note to look for would be if your theme/template/plugins are using src sets. It could be possible that your normal version of the image is fine, but the images in the srcset for mobile are all messed up.

As noted above, completely disable w3 cache to troubleshoot that it's not the issue. Then take a look at the plugins.